# Create dinamically tables only with measures based on slicer selection DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've a calculated table created based on measures and I want filter this table based on a slicer selection from original table. Following the original table:

| Points | city |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | new york |
| 5 | las vegas |
| 3 | san francisco |
| 7 | miami |
| 8 | new york |
| 11 | las vegas |
| 14 | san francisco |
| 8 | miami |
| 17 | new york |
| 30 | miami |

Here are the measures:

```
mean = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('team_base'[Points]))
mean_plus_1 = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('team_base'[Points])+1)
mean_plus_2 = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('team_base'[Points])+2)
```

And the calculated table was builded as follows:

```
agg_team = {("mean",[mean]),("mean_plus_1",[mean_plus_1]),("mean_plus_2",[mean_plus_2])}
```

The output:

| Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| mean | 10.7 |
| mean_plus_1 | 11.7 |
| mean_plus_2 | 12.7 |

However, I want filter the city, for instance by "new york" and get the desiree output:

| Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| mean | 9.67 |
| mean_plus_1 | 10.67 |
| mean_plus_2 | 11.67 |

I know it's possible do it using SELECTEDVALUE function but I'm new in power bi and I don't know how to do it. I also know calculate tables are calculated at refresh time and not in the query interaction, but I want a trick to handle it or some idea of how to solve it without calculated tables.

I need a graph like that with space between the bars which is possible also filtering by a slicer panel. I can't get this result simplying dragging the measures to the clustered bar chart.

[image]

When I filtering "new york" from the city column my desiree output is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your previous question - Calculated Tables will not help you here.
In this case you are going to need to use SELECTEDVALUE.

Create a new Table via 'Enter data' in the Home ribbon.
[image]
Feel free to name the table and column as you wish (but then do update the following measure).

Next create **one** measure like:

```
Agg = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('Calculation'[Calculation]),
  "Mean",     CALCULATE(AVERAGE('team_base'[Points])),
  "Mean + 1", CALCULATE(AVERAGE('team_base'[Points]) + 1),
  "Mean + 2", CALCULATE(AVERAGE('team_base'[Points]) + 2)
)
```

Finally, in your visual, use the new table/column `'Calculation'[Calculation]` together with the new measure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It solved partially my case, there is a way to display all bars and not only the selected bar?

Comment: Please be a clear and specific, update the question with a screen snip.

Comment: I did it. I edited.

Comment: I wasn't clear, apologies - what do you mean by "displaying all bars and not only the selected bar"?

Comment: I want filter by city, for instance "new york" and the graph must displaying the three bars "mean", "mean+1" and "mean+2" with the values associated to each bar

Comment: I updated the post with a last graph with my desiree output. If I understood well the problem with your solution is because the graphs are not displayed at the same time, for instance if I click in the "mean" option from the slicer the graph only will show me the mean column. I want the graph show me three columns and being possible filtering the city.

Comment: Kindly share a full report visual. I would like to see what the "mean" option from the slicer looks like.