# How can I create a clustered bar chart with space among the bars?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Suppose I have the following table:

| Points | city |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | new york |
| 5 | las vegas |
| 3 | san francisco |
| 7 | miami |
| 8 | new york |
| 11 | las vegas |
| 14 | san francisco |
| 8 | miami |
| 17 | new york |
| 30 | miami |

Here are the measures:

```
mean = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('team_base'[Points]))
mean_plus_1 = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('team_base'[Points])+1)
mean_plus_2 = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('team_base'[Points])+2)
```

I want the following output when I creating a bar chart without using calculated table:
[image]

If I simply dragging the measures created above to bar chart the result is bars without space among the bars as following:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create dinamically tables only with measures based on slicer selection DAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77397014/create-dinamically-tables-only-with-measures-based-on-slicer-selection-dax)

Comment: Not really, when I display all bars there are not space between them like the second chart above.

Comment: Simply put, the space between bars comes from having different categories. Multiple measures are not considered different categories. Options available: follow the answer I gave you in using a Dim Table for the category along with SELECTEDVALUE, or see if you can find a custom visual in the market place, or build your own visual with something like Charticulator.