# Separate bars from different tables power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two different tables as following:

sales1:

| date | category | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | A | 200 |
| 02/01/2023 | A | 220 |
| 03/01/2023 | A | 230 |
| 04/01/2023 | A | 210 |
| 05/01/2023 | A | 220 |
| 06/01/2023 | A | 230 |
| 07/01/2023 | A | 130 |
| 08/01/2023 | A | 130 |

sales2:

| date | category | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | B | 200 |
| 02/01/2023 | B | 210 |
| 03/01/2023 | B | 230 |
| 04/01/2023 | B | 220 |
| 05/01/2023 | B | 230 |
| 06/01/2023 | B | 250 |
| 07/01/2023 | B | 260 |

I so created two measures:

sum1 = sum(sales1)

sum2 = sum(sales2)

My idea is to plot these two measures on the same graph and have the following output (with separate columns and not a calculate table):

[image]

Comment: As per your previous question - you need to have a dimension to create categories in these charts. Two separate measures don't count. So either append these two tables and use the category column, or create a single column table with "A" and "B" in separate rows, the use SELECTEDVALUE in your measure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77402410/how-can-i-create-a-clustered-bar-chart-with-space-among-the-bars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want two tables. You can just append one to the other in PowerQuery

```
Table.Combine({Sales1, Sales2})
```

(On both the Sales1 and the Sales2 table, UNcheck Load To Report). Then only the combined query with all the records from Sales1 and Sales2 will be in one table. Then you can create dimension tables (like DimDate).